# Writing an EF enabled ADO.NET provider with Asymmetric Type Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I'm would like to write entity framework provider with some asymmetric type mapping.
In my case, an array of integer on EDM side should be send to the database as a string in the sql text query.

In my opinion the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee828423%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is lacking clarity and samples :

> **Writing a Provider with Asymmetric Type Mapping**
>
> When writing a data store provider for the Entity Framework, the
>   EDM-to-provider type mapping for some types may be different from
>   provider-to-EDM type mapping. For instance, unbounded EDM
>   PrimitiveTypeKind.String may map to nvarchar(4000) on the provider,
>   while nvarchar(4000) maps to the EDM
>   PrimitiveTypeKind.String(MaxLength=4000).
>
> You write an XML file that has two sections:
>
> - A list of provider types expressed in EDM terms and define mapping for both direction: EDM-to-provider and provider-to-EDM.
> - A list of functions supported by the provider where parameter and return types are expressed in EDM terms.

What I've done so far :

- I have the code ready to go back and forth from the integer array to the string.
- I have written the manifest :
- I have added code to :

public override TypeUsage GetEdmType(TypeUsage storeType)
{
}

Where do I tell the driver to use my custom code to translate between the types ?

Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the only way I found was to rewrite the all provider.

public override TypeUsage GetEdmType(TypeUsage storeType) is in the provider manifest (implementation of DbProviderManifest). To implement it you can't derive from the SqlServer implementation because actually the implementation is private. Anyway, you can use the source code according with the license (you can use the EF provider of SQL Server or of other EF providers you can find on the internet).
Once you have your DbProviderManifest implementation you need to make EF to use it.

The EF retrieves the manifest via the method DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest so you need also to rewrite the DbProviderServices implementation.

And so on until I rewrote the all provider.